# Associate floating IP using php-opencloud

Tags: php, openstack, php-opencloud

I have setup a new instance using a script I have written in openstack and now need to assign a floating IP dynamically to it. How would I go about doing this as I cannot find anywhere which documents this?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: My specific question is how do I assign a floating IP to a newly created instance using php-opencloud?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the add floatingIP API functions are here https://github.com/php-opencloud/openstack/blob/master/src/Networking/v2/Extensions/Layer3/Api.php

Comment: essential part should be here

Comment: I think he may using abandoned version ( https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud ) and it's not implemented there.